# How many days between two dates are in a certain month?

Tags: excel

Using Excel formulas, in a cell, I want to calculate how many days that are `>= startdate` and `<= enddate` are in a certain month.

Example
startdate: `2014-01-15`

enddate: `2015-04-02`

month: `january`

formula result: `17 january days in 2014 + 31 january days in 2015 = 48`

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Can you also have many years in between? e.g. start date 2009-01-15 and end date 2015-04-02?

Comment: Yes there can be more than 1 year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach:
Using an array formula which creates an array of dates from start date to startdate + 9999. For this it adds 0, 1, 2, ... 9999 days to the start date until 9999 days are added. Then count how many of those days are in the needed month and lower or equal the end date.

[image]

Formula in `E2` is

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2+ROW($A$1:$A$10000)-1)=D2)*((A2+ROW($A$1:$A$10000)-1)<=B2))
```

Note this works not if there are more than 9999 days between start date and end date.

Comment: Does that need to be an array formula? It seems to work just as well even if I don't press shift+control+enter.

Comment: No, this formula does not need finished with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]. But nevertheless it is an array formula since `SUMPRODUCT` takes all parameters as arrays. One should know this because array formulas are of bad performance with big ranges. So don't use this formula with `ROW($A:$A)` for example.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is worth putting as a separate answer as it is almost the same. It avoids having a max number of days between start and end date, but not everyone likes using INDIRECT: =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2-1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(B2-A2+1))))=D2))

Comment: @Tom Sharpe: Yes, this is another approach since it only creates an array of dates from start to end date. This is better. Oh and `INDIRECT` can be replaced with `INDEX` in this case. `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2-1+ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,B2-A2+1)))=D2))`. Untested. Please test and write an own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on the first answer, using INDIRECT to produce an array of dates between the start and end dates (F1):-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2-1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(B2-A2+1))))=D2))
```

As mentioned by Axel Richter, you can also use INDEX to produce the array of dates (F2):-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2-1+ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,B2-A2+1)))=D2))
```

The advantage of using these formulae is that there is no restriction on the difference between the start and end dates.

The disadvantage of using INDIRECT is that it is volatile and generates a 'SAVE' prompt when the file is closed.

The disadvantage of the INDEX method is that it is vulnerable to row insertion/deletion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is best achieved by using a custom formula. you need to go into VBA (right click on sheet name > edit code), insert a module (right click on sheet name in VBA panel > insert > module) and paste this code:

```
Function DaysInMonthBetween(startDate As Date, endDate As Date, chosenMonth As Integer)
Dim startYear, startMonth, startDay As Integer
Dim endYear, endMonth, endDay As Integer
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim sumDays, daysInMonth As Integer

sumDays = 0

startYear = Year(startDate)
startMonth = month(startDate)
startDay = Day(startDate)

endYear = Year(endDate)
endMonth = month(endDate)
endDay = Day(endDate)

If (startMonth > chosenMonth) Then startYear = startYear + 1
If (endMonth < chosenMonth) Then endYear = endYear - 1

If (endYear >= startYear) Then
    For i = startYear To endYear

        currentDate = DateSerial(i, chosenMonth, 1)
        daysInMonth = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(currentDate, 0))


        sumDays = sumDays + daysInMonth
    Next

    If (startMonth = chosenMonth) Then sumDays = sumDays - (startDay - 1)
    If (endMonth = chosenMonth) Then
        currentDate = DateSerial(endYear, endMonth, 1)
        daysInMonth = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(currentDate, 0))
        sumDays = sumDays - (daysInMonth - endDay)
    End If
End If


DaysInMonthBetween = sumDays
End Function
```

you can then use this custom formula withing the worksheet by typing `=DaysInMonthBetween(startDate, endDate, chosenMonth)`, so if your start date and end date are in A1 and A2, respectively, you would type `=DaysInMonthBetween(A1,A2,1)` to get the result for january, `=DaysInMonthBetween(A1,A2,2)` for february and so on.